# How to get the list of values and keys for a given list field

Tags: 7, entities

I want to programmatically get the list of possible key values for a field, along with their labels. For example:

```
1 => red
2 => blue
3 => Yellow
...
```

and so on. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of getting the field basic data, then get a list of possible values using Field API function that is part of List module.

```
$field = field_info_field([FIELD_MACHINE_NAME]); // This one gets the field data
$field_values = list_allowed_values($field); // This one gets an array of values => labels
$field_key = array_search('red', $show_field_values); // This one gets the key for the value labelled "red", that is: 1
```